# To easily know a Cpu code name by a Linux tool CLI

Tags: cpu

How can we conveniently and easily know a Cpu code name by a Linux tool CLI, ie. not only its feature specification but also e.g for Intel brand

Skylake for Intel Xeon, Intel Celeron
Cherry Trail for Intel Atom
Kaby Lake Intel Core, Intel Celeron
Apollo Lake
?

Thanks before

Answer (score 1):

I'm unaware that you can

What we can do is find out the CPU model, and then build/use some kind of database to tease this information out based on the model.

There is quite a bit of infomation available about the CPUs in the "virtual file" /proc/cpuinfo - so

```
 grep "model name" /proc/cpuinfo | head -1
```

Will get you the CPU model name. There are also other things you can use like prorcessor, model, stepping, which can be useful.

Going back to the model name, for Intel CPU's, many of them follow a format which indicates what generation CPU you are using - see    https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-numbers.html.  On a CPU like

iX-YYY   - the this is a first gen Core CPU
iX-YYYY  - the first Y is the generation.
iX-YYYYY - the first 2 Y's are the generation

Your post is also somewhat mixing incompatible things - Xeon, Celeron, Atom and Core are types of CPU.

Cherry, Kaby Lake, Apollo Lake are generations.  I think (but am not totally sure that the first/first 2 Y letters above give a numeric representation [ which conveniently hints at the year it becomes mainstream] of the generation which can be mapped to Cherry, Kaby, Skylake etc.

Its worth noting that different CPU's have different Flags which can also help fingerprint its capabilities.

Comment: Intel processor names can be found at https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark.html#@Processors  - You may also be able to build a database that gives a moderately good guess using the information at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_CPU_microarchitectures